# GCD for two Cullen numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

The $n$'th [Cullen number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cullen_number) is $C_n = n\cdot2^n+1$.

If $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, what can one say about $\gcd(C_n,C_m)$, where $m$ and $n$ are different positive integers?

Answer (score 3):

It is a result of Luca that

$$\mathrm{gcd}(C_n,C_m)<\exp(c_2(m \log m)^{1/2})$$

for all but finitely many pairs of positive integers $m>n>c_1$, with $c_1, c_2$ two computable constants.

- Florian Luca, [On the greatest common divisor of two Cullen numbers](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02941281.pdf) (2003)

Comment: And,I have and next question:
when Cn divisible by some integer k ?

Comment: A comment on an answer is not the best place to pose a new question.

Comment: For a partial answer to that second question: if $k$ is odd, let the order of $2$ mod $k$ be $m$, a divisor of $\phi(k)$.  Then $n 2^n \mod k$ is periodic in $n$ with period $km$.  Compute which if any of the first $km$ values $n 2^n \mod k$, and this determines the answer.

Comment: In particular, if $k$ and $m$ are coprime, this is always possible with $n \equiv -1 \mod k$ and $n \equiv 0 \mod m$.